# Function para upload de arquivo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou tentando criar uma função que pega 1 valor de um `input do tipo texto` e 1 arquivo.

Eu consegui mover o arquivo para a pasta porém não estou conseguindo desenvolver o SQL para inserir o nome do arquivo no banco.

O ID e nome é inserido normalmente só que o nome do arquivo não é inserido, eu até sei que é na parte:

```
$inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela($campos) VALUES($valores)");
$inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção
```

Porém não estou conseguindo desenvolver algo para incluir esse caminho do arquivo também.

```
function cadastroComFoto($tabela, $dados){
    $con = conectar();

    $nomeArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["name"];
    $nomeTemporario = $_FILES["fotos"]["tmp_name"];
    $tamanhoArquivo = $_FILES["fotos"]["size"];
    $caminho = 'uploads/';

    $arquivoArray = explode(".", $nomeArquivo);
    $extensao = end($arquivoArray);
    $arquivo = $caminho.md5(time().rand(3212, 15452)).'.'.$extensao;

    if (!is_dir($caminho)) {
        mkdir($caminho);
        chmod($caminho, 777);
    }

    if (move_uploaded_file($nomeTemporario, $arquivo)) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
//Percorre os indices passados por POST armazanando em $key e os valores em $val
    $campo[] = $key; // Cria um array $campo com os indices
    $valor[] = "'$val'"; // Cria um array $valor com os valores


    $campos = implode(",", $campo); // Junta os indices de $campo com virgula
    $valores = implode(',', $valor); // Junta os valores de $valor com virgula

}

 // Prepara a inserção no banco de dados
  $inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela($campos) VALUES($valores)");
  $inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção

  if ($inserir) { // Caso a inserção ocorra bem exibira uma mensagem de sucesso.
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Salvo com sucesso!</div>';
  }
  else { // Caso a inserção ocorra mal exibira uma mensagem de erro.
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Erro ao inserir no banco de dados!</div>';
  }
  unset($campos); //Apaga os valores passados por POST --
  unset($valores);// -- para que o usuario não precise sair da pagina e voltar de novo para efetuar outra inserção.
}
print_r($inserir->errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: o problema é esse foreach($_POST as $key => $val) { não tem saída "$_POST" depois de carregar uma saída $_FILES, pegue os atributos de POST antes de FILES,

Comment: @KaduAmaral porque?

Comment: Adicione após o `foreach` as linhas `$campos[] = 'nome da coluna que vai receber o nome do arquivo';` e `$valores[] = $arquivo;`.

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu consegui resolver já! (depois de horas), o problema não é esse que você mencionou.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly eu não tinha reparado que já estava colocando as aspas no `foreach`, por isso tinha comentado aquilo, mas já excluí.

Answer (score -1):

Após o bloco de código:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
   //Percorre os indices passados por POST armazanando em $key e os valores em $val
   $campo[] = $key; // Cria um array $campo com os indices
   $valor[] = "'$val'"; // Cria um array $valor com os valores

   // Junta os indices de $campo com virgula
   $campos = implode(",", $campo); 

   // Junta os valores de $valor com virgula
   $valores = implode(',', $valor); 
}
```

O arquivo não está sendo inserido nas variáveis `$campos` e `$valores` que usas para fazer o `INSERT`, já que arquivos são enviados através da variável `$_FILES`. Então após o `foreach` adicione o campo e valor referente a coluna e nome do arquivo nas variáveis:

```
// Nome da coluna da tabela que vai receber o nome do arquivo no banco de dados
$campos[] = 'arquivo'; 
// Nome do arquivo ou caminho
$valores[] = "'".$arquivo."'";

// Continua o código

// Prepara a inserção no banco de dados
$inserir = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela($campos) VALUES($valores)");
$inseri = $inserir->execute(); // Execute a inserção
```

Answer (score -2):

ola!

depois da funcao move_uploaded_file vc tem um foreach que pega todos os valores dos campos $_POST e prepara o insert.

depois desse foreach vc pode tentar adicionar mais um elemento aos arrays $campos e $valores com os dados do arquivo:

```
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        //Percorre os indices passados por POST armazanando em $key e os valores em $val
        $campo[] = $key; // Cria um array $campo com os indices
        $valor[] = "'$val'"; // Cria um array $valor com os valores


        $campos = implode(",", $campo); // Junta os indices de $campo com virgula
        $valores = implode(',', $valor); // Junta os valores de $valor com virgula

    }

    // inserindo arquivo da pasta uploads na lista do insert
    $campo[] = "arquivo";
    $valores[] = "'$arquivo'";
```